# Съезжают элементы интерфейса в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Работаю с Android Studio, во время тестирования приложения на реальном устройстве съезжают все элементы интерфейса, не только метки, и в итоге находятся совершенно не там, где должны быть(если находятся у края, то в итоге оказываются за границами экрана). Пытался создать новый проект, поиграться с Layout: ставил RelativeLayout(который и указан на скриншотах), ставил ConstrativeLayout - особых плодов это не дало. С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?
Android Studio последней версии 3.4.2 Stable, версия андроид на телефоне 5.1.
Спасибо.
Код из content_main.xml(после создания проекта было добавлено лишь 2 метки и изменено их положение, ничего более добавлено не было):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="161dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="487dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Как должно быть]
[image: Как получается]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_marginTop="487dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="97dp`, думаю, проблема в этом, слишком большие отступы. На реальном устройстве плотность пикселей отличается от такой на виртуальном, что и приводит к расползанию TextView.
Используйте: `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`, чтобы текст прилип к низу и уменшите отступы, а лучше, удалите `android:layout_marginTop="487dp"`.

Comment: Есть не использовать отступы, то да, проблема исчезает и все хорошо. Другая проблема: При добавлении атрибута android:layout_gravity ничего не меняется. http://prntscr.com/og5vpa. Текст как был после всех изменений прилеплен к нижнему правому краю первой метки, так и остается там же. 
И еще вопрос в добавку: Как без использования отступов в таком случае делать элементы не по краям, а в области ближе к центру, например? Используя более маленькие значения отступов и тесты этих значений на моем устройстве или есть более рациональный способ?

Comment: Моя ошибка, android:layout_gravity не работает с RelativeLayout, используйте android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", должен растянуться на все свободное пространство по вертекали, удалив android:layout_below="@id/textView2", TextView прилипнет к низу. Добавив android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" - растяните TextView по ширине и добавив android:gravity="center" вы разместите текст по центру TextView .

Comment: android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" сделает отступ от  низа, но так как он не большой, то это не станет проблемой для дисплеев даже с очень низкой плотностью пикселей. У каждого контейнера (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, TableLayout, ConstraintLayout) своя логика взаимодействия элементов. Поэтому, что работает в одном контейнере, не работает в другом.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог способ с такой строкой:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
```

Только уже индивидуально со значением, смотря как нужно подстроить.